# Is it possible to use Page.Parameters to set the retURL in a VF Component?

Tags: visualforce-component, visual-workflow, parameters

I have been asked to create visual flows for Service Console users for complex Case types.  I'm testing with an existing flow, using a VF Component to create a button that launches the flow.  Clicking the button completely replaces the sidebar with the flow, which is fine, until they reach the end.  At this point, I would like to use retURL to restore the sidebar to its original state.

I can get the flow to open using the

```
public string contactId {get;set;}

public PageReference launchSurvey() {
    PageReference caSurvey = new PageReference('/flow/my_Survey');
    // Assign contactId, passed in from the Console, to varContactId, the Contact.Id variable in the flow
    caSurvey.getParameters().put('varContactId', contactId);
    caSurvey.setRedirect(true);
    return caSurvey;
}
```

syntax, but if I put the retURL directly into the PageReference, the parameter that my flow requires ends up at the end and it fails.

```
PageReference('/flow/Product_Mgmt_Coagulant_Survey?retURL='/apex/myConsoleComponentName'
```

Is it possible to set retURL using Page.getParameters.put('retURL', someValue)?

(What would be really useful would be to open the interview in a subTab(), but '/flow/myInterview' is an external domain and I can't figure out how to whitelist/enable that, either.  Hoping this will spark a solution...)

Thanks!

Duncan